# Find and Replace special char with defined value

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to find and replace if a string contain `/,+,?,-,_,#` any of these into `_sls_,_pls_,_wht_,_dsh_,_usc_,_hsh_` this respectively.

**Example**:

```
'_sls_'=>'/','_pls_'=>'+','_wht_'=>'?','_dsh_'=>'-','_usc_'=>'_','_hsh_'=>'#'

Mary_land = Mary_usc_land
Mary+land = Mary_pls_land
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/f5snutvu/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write all the characters you want to get replaced into a function and call it

```js
var string1 = "Mary_land";
var string2 = "Mary+lang";
var string3 = "Mary#lang";
var string4 = "Mary-lang";
var string5 = "Mary/lang?Maryland";

console.log(normalize(string1));
console.log(normalize(string2));
console.log(normalize(string3));
console.log(normalize(string4));
console.log(normalize(string5));

function normalize(str){
   str = str.replace(/_/g,"_usc_");
   str = str.replace(/\+/g,"_pls_");
   str = str.replace(/\//g,"_sls_");
   str = str.replace(/#/g,"_hsh_");
   str = str.replace(/-/g,"_dsh_");
   str = str.replace(/\?/g,"_wht_");
   return str;
}
```

Comment: How about `'/'` ? Its changing into comment .

Comment: escape special characters using a backslash to make javascript treat them as regular characters. UPdated post.